# Understanding BLAS - RMarkdown and regular R session using different BLAS?

Tags: r

My problem is running an `Rmd` in RStudio runs all chunks perfectly, but knitting (to html document) encounters an obscure error.

To debug, I ran `sessionInfo()` in both a regular R session and inside a clean `Rmd` with the same packages loaded.

The only difference is the R session says

```
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
```

whereas the `Rmd` output of `sessionInfo()` is:

```
BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib
```

Could this be an issue or is it normal for the R session inside RStudio to use a different BLAS to RMarkdown?

In learning about BLAS, I read that [it's the result of calling `extSoftVersion()["BLAS"]`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/sessionInfo.html), which is [documented here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/extSoftVersion.html) and says:

> The name of the binary/executable file for BLAS can be used as an indication of which implementation is in use. Typically, the R version of BLAS will appear as libR.so (libR.dylib), R or libRblas.so (libRblas.dylib), depending on how R was built. Note that libRblas.so (libRblas.dylib) may also be shown for an external BLAS implementation that had been copied, hard-linked or renamed by the system administrator. For an external BLAS, a shared object file will be given and its path/name may indicate the vendor/version. The detection does not work on Windows.

FWIW I tried to simply move the working BLAS into the location of the not-working BLAS (removing the not-working file), but I get

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRblas.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/exec/R
  Reason: image not found
```

Comment: You ran these both inside the same Rstudio session? Or how exactly did you run the R session vs the Rmd file? Do they both return the same path for `R.home()`? BLAS just refers to the matrix math library. It shouldn't effect knitting. But having different values there makes it sound like you have two different versions of R installed.

Comment: @MrFlick I ran `sessionInfo()` inside RStudio. I compared it to `sessionInfo()` inside an Rmd which was empty except for having the same libraries loaded. I knitted the rmd with cmd + shift + k (and viewed the output in the html file)

Comment: @MrFlick I will check for R.home(), one moment

Comment: Echoing Mr Flick here --- something between you, RStudio, and macOS.  On the (Debian / Ubuntu) Linux side we can _formally_ switch which I once used in a package to provide benchmarking support for comparison between BLAS/LAPACK implementations (and the then fashionable GPU alternative), see the writeup in [its vignette](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/gcbd/vignettes/gcbd.pdf).

Comment: @MrFlick I confirm `R.home()` for both RStudio session and Rmd output are identical (`"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources"`)

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel currently the BLAS is the only difference I can spot between the two sessions. Is BLAS something that's likely to cause differences in code execution (and hence possible errors in higher level code)? (my guess is it probably wouldn't cause differences, since algebra should be the same irrespective of BLAS implementation)

Comment: For good measure, I also note `.libPaths()` are identical for both sessions